# Getting value of a particular key of a map in JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl

We are using spring as framework and jsp as front end page.
I have following code in one of the controller. 
In the JSP I would like to get value of "selectedRow" which would be a map, and using that map I would like to get the value(which is a set) for a particular key(don't want to iterate the map) and iterate over it.

```
@Autowired
public NutritionSelection ns;

model.addAttribute("selectedRow", ns.getNutritionDtoList());


@Component
public class NutritionSelection {
    Map<String, Set<NutritionDto>> nutritionDtoList;
.......
}
```

Could some one please help how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance,
Kitty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use EL like so:

```
<c:set var="myVar" value="${selectedRow['yourkey']}"/>
<!--if your page default scope isn't request then:-->
<c:set var="myVar" value="${requestScope.selectedRow['yourkey']}"/>
```